# yiic on Mac Lion doesn't generate webapp

Tags: macos, yii, osx-lion

I have set up Mac Lion as my development machine.  I am not using MAMP and everything is running smoothly.  I have run the yii requirements and everything is good.  Now I am trying to create my first webapp using yiic.  When I follow the instructions here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app terminal tells me it has mkdir a bunch of directories and that my webapp was created successfully.

But the testdrive directory is not in the correct directory (or any directory for that matter)

Has anyone run into this?  And yes the yiic file and framework directory have execute permissions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Brent

Answer (score 2):

The code you link works perfectly on Lion. Are you sure you are doing it in the right place?

```
~/Sites/yii/$> ls ../foo
ls: ../foo: No such file or directory
~/Sites/yii/$> ./framework/yiic webapp ../foo
Create a Web application under '/Users/xcode/Sites/foo'? [Yes|No] yes
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/assets
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/css
   generate css/bg.gif
   generate css/form.css
   generate css/ie.css
   generate css/main.css
   generate css/print.css
   generate css/screen.css
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/images
   generate index-test.php
   generate index.php
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected
   generate protected/.htaccess
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/commands
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/commands/shell
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/components
   generate protected/components/Controller.php
   generate protected/components/UserIdentity.php
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/config
   generate protected/config/console.php
   generate protected/config/main.php
   generate protected/config/test.php
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/controllers
   generate protected/controllers/SiteController.php
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/data
   generate protected/data/schema.mysql.sql
   generate protected/data/schema.sqlite.sql
   generate protected/data/testdrive.db
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/extensions
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/messages
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/migrations
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/models
   generate protected/models/ContactForm.php
   generate protected/models/LoginForm.php
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/runtime
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/tests
   generate protected/tests/bootstrap.php
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/tests/fixtures
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/tests/functional
   generate protected/tests/functional/SiteTest.php
   generate protected/tests/phpunit.xml
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/tests/report
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/tests/unit
   generate protected/tests/WebTestCase.php
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/views
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/views/layouts
   generate protected/views/layouts/column1.php
   generate protected/views/layouts/column2.php
   generate protected/views/layouts/main.php
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/views/site
   generate protected/views/site/contact.php
   generate protected/views/site/error.php
   generate protected/views/site/index.php
   generate protected/views/site/login.php
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/protected/views/site/pages
   generate protected/views/site/pages/about.php
   generate protected/yiic
   generate protected/yiic.bat
   generate protected/yiic.php
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/themes
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/themes/classic
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/themes/classic/views
   generate themes/classic/views/.htaccess
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/themes/classic/views/layouts
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/themes/classic/views/site
      mkdir /Users/xcode/Sites/foo/themes/classic/views/system

Your application has been created successfully under /Users/xcode/Sites/foo.
~/Sites/yii/$> ls ../foo
assets         css            images         index-test.php index.php      protected          
themes
```

NB, Sites for me is the default directory where Lion searches for home page when you enable System Preferences -> Sharing -> Web sharing.